# Change button's background alpha without changing the text alpha value in Android?

Tags: android, xml, graphics

I have a button with an image background and text.
The background alpha should be 0.7 and the text alpha should be 1.0.

```
<Button
android:background="@drawable/button"
android:alpha="0.7"
android:text="Button"
/>
```

By this code I get 0.7 alpha for the whole button. Is there a way to change only the drawable alpha?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
myButton.getBackground().setAlpha(200);
```

can try this in your code.

```
public abstract void setAlpha (int alpha)
```

> Added in API level 1
>
> Specify an alpha value for the drawable. 0 means fully transparent,
>   and 255 means fully opaque.

Comment: Careful with this as it was also affecting other backgrounds for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<Button
    android:background="#3000"
    android:text="Button"
    />
```

here #3000 =>  #argb where 'a' sets the alpha component.